# How To Patch LFI Vulnerabilities

Tags: php, file-inclusion

I wonder how to patch the LFI problem in this code? Please suggest a good way to patch this vulnerability.

[image]

Comment: [Do not post an image of text. That's rude. Copy-paste the text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: This is not something to "patch". You have a design pattern issue. There are multiple tested design patterns for how to process user input to display a valid page.

Comment: Is this from a homework assignment or textbook?

Answer (score 2):

Directory traversal/local file inclusion attacks are just a symptom of the problem of failing to validate user input.  Consider what you're doing:  You're taking input from the Internet and blinding passing it to a function that expects a very particular type of input.

The short answer is:  VALIDATE ALL USER INPUT.

The longer answer is, and in this case, verify that what is being POSTed in the Product variable is a legitimate file name in the appropriate directory.

This same premise is how SQL Injection works.